# Can't get value from radio button ionic 3

Tags: javascript, android, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make multiple choice quiz app with ionic but i confuse how to get score, i think i can get the selected value in radio button to making a score. but i dont understand how to get value from selected radio button in ionic with ngFor loop from database.

this is my html file

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Quiz <ion-icon name="more" (click)="showMore($event)" style="float:right; cursor:pointer; width:20px;"></ion-icon></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <p class="pertanyaan">{{ item.pertanyaan }} </p><br>
    <form>
      <div>
          <input type="radio" name="jwb1" id="jwb1" value="A" [(ngModel)]="jawaban"/>
          <label for="jwb1">{{ item.jawaban1 }}</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="radio" name="jwb1" id="jwb2" value="B" [(ngModel)]="jawaban"/>
          <label for="jwb2">{{ item.jawaban2 }}</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="radio" name="jwb1" id="jwb3" value="C" [(ngModel)]="jawaban"/>
          <label for="jwb3">{{ item.jawaban3 }}</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="radio" name="jwb1" id="jwb4" value="D" [(ngModel)]="jawaban"/>
          <label for="jwb4">{{ item.jawaban4 }}</label>
      </div>

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>

  <button ion-button name="submit" ng-model="submit" (click)="konfirmasiKirim()">Submit</button>

</ion-content>
```

and this my ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-params';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular/components/alert/alert-controller';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-quiz',
  templateUrl: 'quiz.html',
})
export class QuizPage {
  public username:any;
  public jawaban:any;
  public items : any = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public http   : Http,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController)
  {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.username = this.navParams.get('username');
  }


  ionViewWillEnter()
  {
     this.load();
  }

  // Retrieve the JSON encoded data from the remote server
  // Using Angular's Http class and an Observable - then
  // assign this to the items array for rendering to the HTML template
  load()
  {
     this.http.get('https://apifisika.000webhostapp.com')
     .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(data =>
     {
        this.items = data;
     });
  }

  konfirmasiKirim()
  {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Kirim Jawaban?',
      message: 'Hai '+this.username+' sudah yakin untuk kirim jawaban?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cek kembali',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('mengko');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Kirim Jawaban',
          handler: () => {
            // this.navCtrl.push(QuizPage);
            alert(this.jawaban);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }

}
```

In my database there are 10 question, So i need to get value from each question, for example number 1 i choose a, number 2 b, ... number 10 i choose d. And then i get all the value above to make a scoring.

Can someone help me to get selected value in radio button with *ngFor loop? pls

Answer (score 0):

tweak the code of `this.items = data;` to be

```
this.items.forEach(item => {
   item.isSelected = false;
});
```

and in your HTML do ngModel on this value like so:

```
<form>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <p class="pertanyaan">{{ item.pertanyaan }} </p>
     <div>
          <input type="radio" name="jwb{{ item.jawaban1 }}" id="jwb{{ item.jawaban1 }}"  [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected"/>
          <label for="jwb1">{{ item.jawaban1 }}</label>
     </div>   
</div>

</form>
```

and to display the results as a score of total:

`<h3>{{ totalSelected() }}</h3>`

and in your ts within your class add the following function:

```
totalSelected(){
   return this.items.filter(item => return item.isSelected).length
}
```

That's it, I'm ready to tweak it for you if you want to calculate each selected answer passed on some certain condition and/or return a specific weight for the correct answer